# Pass a role to authenticate basic http from postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

I am using `Spring boot security` and defined user in memory authentication to authenticate `http basic` but I am not seeing option in `Postman` to pass user role so my question is how can i pass role in `postman` for all requests??

```
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("passowrd"))
          .authorities("ADMIN");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass `Role` from Postman request as `inMemoryAuthentication` you have set `user` with role `"ADMIN"` so path you have defined can be accessed by `ADMIN` role and if you try to call end points by this user, you will have access as "user" as role is `"ADMIN"` in your memory where user will be authenticated in basic auth.

So from Postman just select `Basic Auth` and pass `user as user` and `password as password`, you will be able to call those end points for which have defined to access by `"hasRole = ADMIN.`.